# Como funciona o dropDownList?

Tags: php, html, yii, dropdownlist

Meu código esta apenas para adicionar texto, estou usando o framework yii 1, gostaria de criar um dropDownList com as opções feminino e masculino apenas.

```html
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'ALU_SEXO'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'ALU_SEXO',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a própria documentação do framework você pode gerar o dropDownList com o método estático de mesmo nome do CHtml

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', $select, 
          array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'));
```

src: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh5